# What should a view contain in an MVC?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

I am currently working with `Swift` and I was learning about **MVC** - one question that popped out was this: I am trying to implement a `WKWebView` - and I already know how to do this within a **ViewController**.

My question is: should I create my own **WebView class** to place the `WKWebView` or should I only house it with in the **ViewController**? I am trying to follow the **MVC structure**.

Comment: MVC is a pattern for organizing your code. I'm not sure what you mean by *in an MVC*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a web *view*, so it should be placed in the view controller in the storyboard. This really has nothing to do with MVC, *per se*.

- The view controller is your **C**ontroller.
- The view controller's root view and the web view you're putting in it are the **V**iew.
- The **M**odel may or may not be relevant here since a model is usually just a data structure that the **C**ontroller uses to populate the **V**iew. It could just be the HTML that you pass to the web view.

Comment: FWIW, it is debatable to claim that the view controller necessarily _is_ the “controller”. This certainly is how Apple tends to describe it, but many of us abstract business logic out of view controllers and into UIKit-independent controller objects (for improved testability, to avoid massive view controllers, etc.) and only use the view controller to mediate between the UIKit-independent controller objects and the UI. In these patterns (and there are many variations) the view controller tends to be considered part of the view, not a true controller. But with that caveat, good answer!

Comment: In my opinion, the whole "massive view controller" label is a bogeyman that's blown way out of proportion. In my experience, most view controllers are simple enough not to need MVVM, and when the view controllers *have* gotten too big, I usually find it more useful to factor out the *view* logic than the *model* (or server interop) logic. Then again, SwiftUI throws out all the rules and gets rid of the explicit controller altogether.

Comment: I agree that moving detailed view-specific logic into views (or in some cases, into child view controllers) is important. On the broader observation, I really didn’t want to debate the point, but, for the sake of future readers, only to say that it is debatable. But, again, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: should I create my own WebView class to place the WKWebView or should I only house it within the ViewController? I am trying to follow the MVC structure.

The *view* in *Model View Controller* really refers to a view and its entire graph of subviews. If a `WKWebView` instance is the view that contains everything that the controller will manage, then it's fine to make that "the" view; there's no need to put it inside another view just for the sake of containing it. On the other hand, if you want the same controller to manage other views not contained in the web view, then you can put the web view and the others all inside some other view and let the controller manage that.

How you organize your views really isn't determined by MVC -- just do what works. MVC really speaks to the way that the information your app operates on is owned and managed by a *model*, displayed in a *view*, and how the interactions between model and view are mediated by the *controller*.